# How can I prevent a product to be added to cart without show any messages?

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart

I'm trying to prevent a product to be added to cart without showing any messages. In order to do that I'm using a `beforeAddProduct` plugin and it works well but it shows an exception message in order to prevent the product to be added. How can I do that without showing any messages?

```
public function beforeAddProduct(Cart $subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo=null)
    {
      ...
      $product = $productInfo;
      ...

            if ($product)
            {
                // check for existence of product in cart...
                if($this->cartSession->getQuote()->hasProductId($product->getId())){
                    

                    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                        __("I'd like this error should not appear and simply prevent adding the product to the cart!" )
                     );

                }
                
            }


       

        return [$productInfo, $requestInfo];

    }
```

Comment: What if you just remove the `throw new....` code?

Comment: Hello, if I remove the exception it simply adds the product to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Althouth it's generally not recommended to use the *around plugins*, you could actually create one on the same method and call the `proceed()` method only when the product which is intended to be added to cart doesn't already exist in the cart.

Comment: Could you provide a detailed example?

Answer (score -1):

i used an observer "**checkout_cart_product_add_before**"
in etc/fronend/events.xml add this

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_before">
        <observer name="DisableAddToCartOnDefault" instance="Vendor\module\Observer\DisableAddToCart"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

then create class Vendor\module\Observer\DisableAddToCart.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
/**
 */
class DisableAddToCart implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getData("product");
        $requestInfo = $observer->getData("info");
        if ($condition) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(__(""));
        }
    }
}
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this option. This is not how exceptions should be used. Moreover, exception raising inside observers without proper exception treatment is going to disrupt the flow.

Comment: the question is about disrupting the flow of adding to cart on a condition, so i still think this  is the proper solution to the problem